# Why does GET ajax call return an error code 500?

Tags: javascript, laravel

So I have this page with a list of items and a search bar that dinamically searches through all items based on inserted text. I placed an eventHandler on the input to make and ajax call each time input changes to do the filtering.

On another view, I tried implementing the same logic, but instead with tags on checkboxes. At first I just placed alerts to make sure my javascript was receiving all tags properly,nothing wrong so far. Then I tried to make another ajax call and log the result to see if he output was how i intended. This time i got a "GET *link* 500 (Internal Server Error)".

Im using Laravel 8.

This is the view corresponding of the checkboxes:

```
    @foreach($categories as $category)
                    <li class="list-group-item">
                        <div class="form-check">
                            <input class="form-check-input filtercheckbox" type="checkbox" name="checkboxfilter" id="{{$category}}check" value="{{$category}}">
                            <label class="form-check-label" for="inlineRadio1">{{strtoupper($category[0]).substr($category,1)}}</label>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    @endforeach
```

My javascript:

```
function filterItems(){
    var filter = [];
    for(var i=0; i<checkbox.length; i++) {
        if(checkbox[i].checked){
            filter.push(checkbox[i].value);
        }
    }

    $.ajax({
        url:"/aluno/shop/filter",
        method:"GET",
        data:{ filter:filter },
        dataType:"json",
        success:function (data) {
            console.log(data);
            //document.getElementById('items_list').innerHTML = data;
        }
        }
    );
}
var checkbox = document.getElementsByClassName("filtercheckbox");

for(var i=0; i<checkbox.length; i++) {
    checkbox[i].addEventListener("change",filterItems);
}
```

And my function controller:

```
public function filterCategory(Request $request){
        if($request->ajax()){
            $query = $request->get('filter');
            $materials = array();

            if( $query != ''){
                foreach ($query as $cat){
                    $materialsList = Material::where('category','=', $cat)->get();
                    array_push($materials,$materialsList);
                }
            }else{
                $materialsList = Material::all();
            }

            if($materials->count() > 0){
                $output = "";
                foreach ($materialsList as $material){
                    $output .= "<div class='col'>" .
                        "<div class='card mt-2'>" .
                        "<img class='shopImage' src='" . $material['image'] .  "' alt='product'/>" .
                        "<div class='card-body'>" .
                        "<h5 class='card-title'>" . $material['name'] . "</h5>" .
                        "</div>" .
                        "<ul class='list-group list-group-flush'>" .
                        "<li class='list-group-item'>Quantidade:" .  $material['amount'] . "</li>" .
                        "<li class='list-group-item'>Categoria:" . strtoupper($material['category'][0]).substr($material['category'],1) . "</li>" .
                        "<li class='list-group-item'><a href='" . route('edit_item',$material['id']) . "' class='btn btn-primary'>Editar</a></li>" .
                        "</ul>" .
                        "</div>" .
                        "</div>";
                }
            } else {
                $output = 'Item com esse nome não encontrado!';
            }

            $data = $output;
            echo json_encode($data);
        }
    }
```

And my route is:

```
Route::get('/aluno/shop/filter', [App\Http\Controllers\ShopController::class,'filterCategory'])->name('shop_filter');
```

Since dd() function doesen't work in this case, i haven't been able to tell what seems to be the problem, if with the call,the response or anything in between. Aprecciated some help, I can also show how I made the other ajax call regarding the text search, dont know if it might be any conflict.

Comment: 500 indicates an error on the server side. You are probably accessing a value which does not exist, if the error does not occur all the time.

Comment: Check the log entry to get more details. By default the debug log entries can be found in `/storage/logs/laravel.log` file most recent entry at the end of file

Comment: Under no circumstances should your controller methods be generating HTML like that. Use a view!

Comment: Apparently `$materials->count() > 0` could be a cause for error as $materials is initiated as an array and  `->count()` does not exist on array

Comment: You're right @Donkarnash . By changing to php count(), I now get the proper response! If you can make an anwer ill just make close this up

Comment: Posted as answer @Phil as you suggested

Comment: @miken32 There's a growing trend of "server-fetched-partials" where in an ajax request is made to receive html fragment. Even github is using the approach - https://github.com/sponsors look at "Explore the GitHub Sponsors Community" open devtools > network > xhr and click on "Refresh" button and see the response - html fragment

Comment: @Donkarnash yes but that HTML should be stored in a view and not generated in the controller.

Comment: @miken32 Yes agree

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The apparent issue lies in `$materials->count() > 0` within the if statement.

$materials is initiated as an array and `->count()` doesn't exist on array.

Change `if($materials->count() > 0)` to `if(count($materials) > 0)` and it should work

```php
public function filterCategory(Request $request){
        if($request->ajax()){
            $query = $request->get('filter');
            $materials = array();

            if( $query != ''){
                foreach ($query as $cat){
                    $materialsList = Material::where('category','=', $cat)->get();
                    array_push($materials,$materialsList);
                }
            }else{
                $materialsList = Material::all();
            }

            if(count($materials) > 0){    //Changed
                $output = "";
                foreach ($materialsList as $material){
                    $output .= "<div class='col'>" .
                        "<div class='card mt-2'>" .
                        "<img class='shopImage' src='" . $material['image'] .  "' alt='product'/>" .
                        "<div class='card-body'>" .
                        "<h5 class='card-title'>" . $material['name'] . "</h5>" .
                        "</div>" .
                        "<ul class='list-group list-group-flush'>" .
                        "<li class='list-group-item'>Quantidade:" .  $material['amount'] . "</li>" .
                        "<li class='list-group-item'>Categoria:" . strtoupper($material['category'][0]).substr($material['category'],1) . "</li>" .
                        "<li class='list-group-item'><a href='" . route('edit_item',$material['id']) . "' class='btn btn-primary'>Editar</a></li>" .
                        "</ul>" .
                        "</div>" .
                        "</div>";
                }
            } else {
                $output = 'Item com esse nome não encontrado!';
            }

            $data = $output;
            echo json_encode($data);
        }
    }
```